# Evitar repetir funciones iguales JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

¿Cómo puedo evitar que la función JS se repita una vez por cada línea? Es decir, ahora hay tres funciones, pero si hubiese 100 líneas en el formulario me gustaría tener una única función para todas y una por línea.

```js
$( function() {
  $("#id_categoria_1").change( function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "1") {
          $("#id_input_1").prop("disabled", true);
      } else {
          $("#id_input_1").prop("disabled", false);
      }
  });
});      

$( function() {
  $("#id_categoria_2").change( function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "1") {
          $("#id_input_2").prop("disabled", true);
      } else {
          $("#id_input_2").prop("disabled", false);
      }
  });
});     

$( function() {
  $("#id_categoria_3").change( function() {
      if ($(this).val() === "1") {
          $("#id_input_3").prop("disabled", true);
      } else {
          $("#id_input_3").prop("disabled", false);
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            
<form method="post" action="#"> 
    <div style="margin-top:20px;">Fila 1</div>
    <div>
        <select name='id_categoria_1' id='id_categoria_1'>
            <option value="1" selected>Desactivado</option>
            <option value="2">Activado</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_input_1" type="text" disabled>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:20px;">Fila 2</div>
    <div>
        <select name='id_categoria_2' id='id_categoria_2'>
            <option value="1" selected>Desactivado</option>
            <option value="2">Activado</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_input_2" type="text" disabled>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:20px;">Fila 3</div>
    <div>
        <select name='id_categoria_3' id='id_categoria_3'>
            <option value="1" selected>Desactivado</option>
            <option value="3">Activado</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_input_3" type="text" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Puedes resumir todo a una sola función dinámica la cual va a detectar a que `select` se le aplicó el cambio y cual es el elemento `input` hermano de ese `select`, para habilitarlo/deshabilitarlo según sea el caso:

```js
$( function() {
  $(".categoria").change(function(){
    if ($(this).val() === "1") {
      $(this).siblings('input').prop("disabled", true);
    }else{
      $(this).siblings('input').prop("disabled", false);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                            
<form method="post" action="#"> 
    <div style="margin-top:20px;">Fila 1</div>
    <div>
        <select name='id_categoria_1' id='id_categoria_1' class="categoria">
            <option value="1" selected>Desactivado</option>
            <option value="2">Activado</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_input_1" type="text" disabled>
    </div>

    <div style="margin-top:20px;">Fila 2</div>
    <div>
        <select name='id_categoria_2' id='id_categoria_2' class="categoria">
            <option value="1" selected>Desactivado</option>
            <option value="2">Activado</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_input_2" type="text" disabled>
    </div>
    <div style="margin-top:20px;">Fila 3</div>
    <div>
        <select name='id_categoria_3' id='id_categoria_3' class="categoria">
            <option value="1" selected>Desactivado</option>
            <option value="3">Activado</option>
        </select>
        <input id="id_input_3" type="text" disabled>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Muy coqueta.. ¿que hace el siblings?

Comment: Hola @elporfirio, el método siblings() permite seleccionar un hermano directo de un elemento, en este caso el hermano directo de <select> es un <input>, saludos !